# How to write files into the app tree in ember-cli preprocessTree hook

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs, ember-cli-addons

I have a broccoli plugin which does the following:

- Read json file from root folder
- based on the JSON generate some route template HBS files

This works perfectly and can also be acceptance tested by triggering a broccoli build.

Example result of the broccoli build:

```
templates/generated-route.hbs
templates/my-sub/generated.hbs
```

The next phase is integrating it into an ember-addon, and I created one with a `preprocessTree` hook.

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'route-template-generator',

  included(app) {
    this._super.included.apply(this, arguments);

    this.options = Object.assign({}, app.options);
    this.appName = app.name;

    if (!this.options.trees) {
        throw new Error('No trees found in app to add the new files to');
    }
    if (!this.appName) {
        throw new Error('no valid application name, unable to add files to the tree');
    }
  },

  preprocessTree(type, tree) {
    if (type === 'template') {
      const extraTemplates = new RouteTemplateGenerator(
        [new Funnel(this.options.trees.app, { include: ['router.json'] })], 
        { destDir: this.appName }
      );

      return mergeTrees([tree, extraTemplates], { overwrite: true });
    }
    return tree;
  }
};
```

The problem with above solution is that the trees cannot be merged if no `destDir` is passed. The ember-app tree is prefixed with the application name, e.g.:

```
my-ember-app-name/templates/application.hbs
my-ember-app-name/router.js
...
```

When calling this addon immediately from a ember-app the `app.options.trees.app` will work, however when this addon is called as dependency from another addon, the parameter in the `included` hook gets an addon object which doesn't have the app tree name.

So the question is, how do I write files to an app tree the right way?

Answer (score 0):

In most addons where this is needed there is a block of code like

```
included(app) {
  this._super.included.apply(this, arguments)
  let current = this;
  // Keep iterating upward until we don't have a grandparent.
  // Has to do this grandparent check because at some point we hit the project.
  do {
    app = current.app || app;
  } while (current.parent.parent && (current = current.parent));

  this.app = app;
},
```

source: https://github.com/FortAwesome/ember-fontawesome/blob/master/index.js#L158-L163

There is also a private method `this._findHost()` that does this, but it isn't available in all versions of ember-cli (and is private).